# Ubuntu 16. Startup finished in 1min 32.747s (kernel)

Tags: boot, kernel

From plot.html that I created using systemd-analyze plot > plot.html, here is I got:

```
Startup finished in 1min 32.747s (kernel) + 18.861s (userspace) = 1min 51.609s
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MyName (Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016) x86-64
```

From systemd-blame, I have this:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
         17.159s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          7.933s apparmor.service
          6.241s dev-sda5.device
          2.770s snapd.refresh.service
          2.291s thermald.service
          1.953s NetworkManager.service
          1.348s ModemManager.service
          1.330s accounts-daemon.service
          1.122s grub-common.service
           919ms lightdm.service
           894ms systemd-udevd.service
           809ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           677ms systemd-sysctl.service
           648ms udisks2.service
           596ms plymouth-start.service
           519ms systemd-journald.service
           476ms apport.service
           415ms systemd-localed.service
           395ms gpu-manager.service
           380ms dns-clean.service
           360ms ufw.service
           360ms dev-hugepages.mount
           359ms dev-mqueue.mount
           359ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           359ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           326ms irqbalance.service
           317ms systemd-modules-load.service
           310ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0b7bc590\x2dc768\x2d4bf3\x2d85ba\x2d1a3d7c5
           310ms systemd-logind.service
           301ms ondemand.service
           288ms console-setup.service
           286ms speech-dispatcher.service
           284ms alsa-restore.service
           274ms systemd-user-sessions.service
           273ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           266ms pppd-dns.service
           266ms rsyslog.service
           261ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           256ms avahi-daemon.service
           256ms systemd-random-seed.service
           224ms resolvconf.service
           205ms networking.service
           147ms polkitd.service
           142ms upower.service
           121ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            92ms colord.service
            87ms plymouth-read-write.service
            50ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            45ms systemd-hostnamed.service
            42ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            25ms user@1000.service
             9ms systemd-timesyncd.service
             4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             3ms ureadahead-stop.service
             3ms rtkit-daemon.service
             1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
           772us rc-local.service
           280us snapd.socket
```

Please help me to find a solution for this, what is really happening?